# confirm still deletes after canceling in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to confirm before the user deletes the review but on confirm it deletes it but does the same when I click cancel

Comment: Its looks like the problem is on line 6 of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send ajax only on confirmation.

```
 function Deletereview(id) { 
    //delete a book 

    //Get a confirmation first
    if (!confirm("Really send?")) {
        return;
    }

    //Your Ajax call
    $.ajax({ 
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't hurt to add the return value to a variable.

var answer = confirm("Really send?");

if (answer){ // do stuff}